# What is the best algorithm to sort a list on the basis of two criteria?

Tags: java, algorithm, list, sorting

I have a list which I need to sort based on two criteria.
The first criterion is a `Boolean`, let's say `isBig`. The second one is a `Long`, which represents a timestamp.

I need to order the elements of the list in this way: before the `isBig = true`, and then the `isBig = false`. Within these groups, the single elements should be ordered descending on the basis of their timestamp.

Basically, I expect the result to be something like this:

```
isBig - 2015/10/29
isBig - 2015/10/28
isBig - 2015/10/27
!isBig - 2015/10/30
!isBig - 2015/10/27
!isBig - 2015/10/26
```

Let's say the object is this:

```
public class Item {
    Boolean isBig;
    Long timestamp;
    // ...
}
```

and the list is just `List<Item> list`.

I figured out that one method would be make three for-cycles: the first to make up the two groups: `isBig` and `!isBig`. The second and the third for sorting the elements within them. Finally I merge the two lists.

Is there a more efficient algorithm for sorting lists on the basis of two criteria?

Comment: You could simply use a custom comperator and use `Collections.sort`.

Comment: Define 'best'. How big is your list? Is your environment memory constrained? What are the speed requirements?

Comment: Concerning efficiency: it would be nicer to use `boolean` and `long` - the primitive types, as they are faster and save memory.

Comment: Thanks @AdriaanKoster, you're right. The list is fairly big but not huge: from 10 elements up to a few hundreds; let's say an average of 100 elements. I'm on Android, so speed and responsiveness should be as much high as reasonably possible.

Comment: A few hundred isn't actually very much...

Comment: @Gianluca 100s is done in milliseconds mate, u got no problem with speed

Comment: That's interesting, thank you @ciamej and @nafas!! Still, just for the sake of personal interest, I would like to understand which is the most efficient solution :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an array using two different criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134303/sorting-an-array-using-two-different-criteria)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can sort the list directly using a custom comparison method which checks both criteria.

Use the `Collections.sort` method and pass a custom comparator with the method `compare` overriden to:

```
 int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
   if (o1.isBig && !o2.isBig)
     return -1;
   if (!o1.isBig && o2.isBig)
     return 1;
   if (o1.timestamp < o2.timestamp)
     return -1;
   if (o1.timestamp > o2.timestamp)
     return 1;
   return 0;
 }
```

If you are obsessed with performance you could possibly speed it up by a few percents with a more sophisticated approach, but for a list of a few hundred elements the gains would be negligible.

An optimized comparison method:

```
int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
   int bigness = (o2.isBig ? 2 : 0) - (o1.isBig ? 2 : 0);
   long diff = o1.timestamp - o2.timestamp;
   return bigness + (int) Long.signum(diff);
}
```

It features no conditional branches what means it will probably be faster than the naive version above.

That's probably everything that can be done for performance. If we knew something more about your data (for instance there are always more big object than small ones, or all the timestamps are unique, or all the timestamps are from a certain narrow range etc) we could probably propose some better solution. However, when we assume that your data is arbitrary and has no specific pattern than the very best solution is to use a standard sort utility like I've shown above.

Splitting the list into two sublists and sorting them separately will definitely be slower. Actually the sorting algorithm will most probably divide the data into two groups and then recursively into four groups, and so on. However, the division won't follow the `isBig` criterion. If you want to learn more, read how [quick sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) or [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) work.

Comment: a ternary operator does feature a conditional branch. So you reduced the branches from 4 to 2. There is a good chance the first version would be optimized with less branches by the JVM.

Comment: Ternaty operator does not feature a conditional branch. The code is not dependent on the evaluation of the ternary operator. Actually if you'd check the machine code there will be no jumps at all in this routine.

Comment: so I did check the Java bytecode for the compare method and for sure I see the code `ifeq` twice. It's basically the same as an if statement.

Comment: Let me check this. x86 (and most other processor achitectures) feature a special instruction called `cmov` which is the equivalent of a ternary operator expression in programming languages. I'm pretty sure this code should be (ultimately) compiled to a `cmov` instruction.

Comment: That is correct. But since ternary and if produce virtually identical Java bytecode, when this bytecode is compiled to assembly the optimizer can use `cmov` for either.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, the approach using two separate lists should be *faster* than the approach using a two-step `Comparator`, because a comparison based on one field is obviously faster than a comparison based on two. By using two lists you are speeding up the part of the algorithm that has `O(n log n)` time complexity (the sort), at the expense of an additional initial stage (splitting into two pieces) which has time complexity `O(n)`. Since `n log n > n`, the two lists approach should be faster for very, very large values of `n`.

However, in practice we are talking about such tiny differences in times that you have to have extremely long lists before the two lists approach wins out, and so it's very difficult to demonstrate the difference using lists before you start running into problems such as an `OutOfMemoryError`.

However, if you use arrays rather than lists, and use clever tricks to do it in place rather than using separate data structures, it is possible to beat the two-step `Comparator` approach, as the code below demonstrates. Before anybody complains: yes I know this is not a proper benchmark!

Even though `sort2` is faster than `sort1`, I would probably not use it in production code. It is better to use familiar idioms and code that obviously works, rather than code that is harder to understand and maintain, even if it slightly faster.

```
public class Main {

    static Random rand = new Random();

    static Compound rand() {
        return new Compound(rand.nextBoolean(), rand.nextLong());
    }

    static Compound[] randArray() {
        int length = 100_000;
        Compound[] temp = new Compound[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            temp[i] = rand();
        return temp;
    }

    static class Compound {
        boolean bool;
        long time;

        Compound(boolean bool, long time) {
            this.bool = bool;
            this.time = time;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) 
                return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) 
                return false;
            Compound compound = (Compound) o;
            return bool == compound.bool && time == compound.time;
        }   

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int result = (bool ? 1 : 0);
            result = 31 * result + (int) (time ^ (time >>> 32));
            return result;
        }
    }

    static final Comparator<Compound> COMPARATOR = new Comparator<Compound>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Compound o1, Compound o2) {
            int result = (o1.bool ? 0 : 1) - (o2.bool ? 0 : 1);
            return result != 0 ? result : Long.compare(o1.time, o2.time);
        }
    };

    static final Comparator<Compound> LONG_ONLY_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<Compound>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Compound o1, Compound o2) {
            return Long.compare(o1.time, o2.time);
        }
    };

    static void sort1(Compound[] array) {
        Arrays.sort(array, COMPARATOR);
    }

    static void sort2(Compound[] array) {
        int secondIndex = array.length;
        if (secondIndex == 0)
            return;
        int firstIndex = 0;
        for (Compound c = array[0];;) {
            if (c.bool) {
                array[firstIndex++] = c;
                if (firstIndex == secondIndex)
                    break;
                c = array[firstIndex];
            } else {
                Compound c2 = array[--secondIndex];
                array[secondIndex] = c;
                if (firstIndex == secondIndex)
                    break;
                c = c2;
            }
        }
        Arrays.sort(array, 0, firstIndex, LONG_ONLY_COMPARATOR);
        Arrays.sort(array, secondIndex, array.length, LONG_ONLY_COMPARATOR);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {

        // Warm up the JVM and check the algorithm actually works.
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            Compound[] arr1 = randArray();
            Compound[] arr2 = arr1.clone();
            sort1(arr1);
            sort2(arr2);
            if (!Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2))
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            System.out.println(i);
        }

        // Begin the test proper.
        long normal = 0;
        long split = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Compound[] array1 = randArray();
            Compound[] array2 = array1.clone();

            long time = System.nanoTime();
            sort1(array1);
            normal += System.nanoTime() - time;

            time = System.nanoTime();
            sort2(array2);
            split += System.nanoTime() - time;

            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println("COMPARATOR:           " + normal);
            System.out.println("LONG_ONLY_COMPARATOR: " + split);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, using a `Collections.sort' will be faster. Usually, it internally uses a merge sort, which means the list will be divided into two groups and subsequently merged anyways. However, mergesort will divide the list in a fairer way. Moreover, it will divide and merge in place.

Comment: @ciamej I think you're wrong, but I'm not 100% sure. I'm in the process of coding up a test.

Comment: Please check if the performance of your solution depends on whether there is a roughly equivalent number of objects for which `isBig` is true and for which `isBig` is false.

Answer (score 2):

The following things you need to do to have two comparable objects for sorting on two parameters.

1. You need to implement Comparator for two comparable objects that you have is one Boolean and one Timestamp.
2. you need to pass these comparators to Collections.sort() because as they are objects that compared for two keys and the data structure is not of primitives they need Collections.sort().

   ```
   /**
    * Comparator to sort employees list or array in order of Salary
    */
   public static Comparator<BooleanComaprator> booleanComparator= new Comparator<BooleanComaprator>() {

       @Override
       public int compare(BooleanComaprator e1, BooleanComaprator e2) {
           if (e1.isBig && !e2.isBig)
               return -1;
           if (!e1.isBig && e2.isBig)
               return 1;
           else 
               return 0;
       }
   }
   ```

   use this object in `Collections.sort(booleanComparator);`

Answer (score 1):

This is called sorting by multiple keys, and it's easy to do.  If you're working with a sort library function that takes a comparator callback function to decide the relative ordering of two elements, define the comparator function so that it first checks whether the two input values a and b have equal `isBig` values, and, if not, immediately returns `a.isBig > b.isBig` (I'm assuming here that `>` is defined for boolean values; if not, substitute the obvious test).  But if the `isBig` values are equal, you should return `a.timestamp > b.timestamp`.

Answer (score 1):

You can a define a custom comparator and use it to sort the `List`. E.g.

```
class ItemComparator implements Comparator {
    @Override
    public int compare (Item a, Item b) {
        int bc = Boolean.compare(a.isBig, b.isBig);
        if (bc != 0)
            return bc;
        return Long.compare(a.timestamp, b.timestamp);
    }
}
```

and use it like this

```
Collections.sort(list, ItemComparator);
```

Comment: you cast a long to an int in the return statement - that might go wrong!

Comment: @ciamej objection sustained. I used `Long.compare` instead.